# Insert multiple items in a layout

Tags: java, android, android-layout

Im developing an Android app in Java using Android Studio. I have a layout called `activity_way_bill`, where it must show a list of trips. Also, I have a layout called `item_waybill_trip`, where I have labels for displaying the trips details. 
I need to insert X `item_waybill_trip` layouts into the `activity_way_bill` layout (the X number I will know at runtime). Right now, I just have it included like this, in the XML file:

```
<include android:id="@+id/trip" layout="@layout/item_waybill_trip" />
```

But this is a static solution and only allows me to include 1 (or a predefined number) of layouts. I need to include X, and set different texts for each one. How can I do this?

Comment: please have look at:
https://proandroiddev.com/how-to-implement-a-recyclerview-33fd4ff9988e

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to display the list of element with the same layout but different data than you have to use  `recycle view.`

You can also define the count at runtime and change the count if you needed.

You can visit the site below and check how to use  `recycle view.`  :-
https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/recyclerview

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the answer by @Mahavir Jain you could use a recyclerview for that but if you want to go the other way, you will have to create the dynamic layouts at runtime and add them to the parent layout using the `.addView()` method of the parent layout

Answer (score 0):

If your app needs to display a scrolling list of elements based on large data sets (or data that frequently changes), you should use [RecyclerView](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/recyclerview) as described on this page.